# NSURL with string relative to URL returning unexpected result

Tags: ios, xcode, afnetworking-2, nsurl

This is the call I am making:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"rooms" relativeToURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"localhost:9000"]];
```

and the result of url.absoluteURL is:

```
localhost:///rooms
```

does this make sense? I was expecting the result to be `localhost:9000/rooms`

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a `scheme`. `NSURL` seems to interpret the `localhost:` part as scheme, which causes unexpected behaviour. In case of `http` you should try this:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"rooms" relativeToURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:9000/"]];
```